# Moving to the last Fieldsets

Tags: javascript, fieldset, action-button

I have a form with 5 fieldsets each with Next & Previous buttons. A checking button is added to the last fieldset to check the required fields. After filling up the required fields, I need to add another button in each fieldset to jump direct to the submit fieldset without passing in each fieldset again. Any help to do so? Thank you.

Comment: Post some code, otherwise it's hard to help...

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding IDs to the fieldsets with numbering on them:

```
<fieldset id="fs_0"></fieldset>
<fieldset id="fs_1"></fieldset>
<fieldset id="fs_2"></fieldset>
<fieldset id="fs_3"></fieldset>
<fieldset id="fs_4"></fieldset>
```

Then with javascript you can do a loop:

```
for(var i = 0: i < 4; i++){}
```

Since you don't need a button on the last fieldset, the for loop has a limit of 4. At the end you can do something like this:

```
for(var i = 0: i < 4; i++){

    var btn = document.createElement('button');//create button
    btn.onclick = function(){ jumpToEnd();};//add function to do
    btn.innerHTML = 'JUMP';//what will it show
    document.getElementById('fs_' + i).appendChild(btn);//append to fieldset
}
```

EDIT: Syntax

Comment: I have id for each fieldset but without numbers. I tried to use some of your Javascript but it did not work with me. I already have Next-Previous buttons in each fieldset/tab and wanna add extra button in each fieldset to jum to the last fieldset/page.

Comment: I used numbering so I could call the fieldsets through the loop. Hmm, interesting. Could you provide some code? I just can't get around what could be happening.